# Visual Studio Code App wont run from Applications folder

Tags: applications, install, macos

The latest version of Visual Studio Code will not run ("can't be opened" is the unhelpful error) when I copy it to the applications folder.  It runs fine after unzipping to the Downloads folder, but just wont from the applications folder.

I don't think it's the security setting as that's already set to allow apps from anywhere.

OS X El Capitan on a Mid-2014 Macbook Pro

Comment: I'd check the execute bit is set for everyone; I've had vague weirdness like that, where the actuall app inside the package didn't arrive with execute perms

Comment: any link as to how?  its not my main machine, and not had to do this before.

Comment: Use [BatChmod](http://www.lagentesoft.com/batchmod/index.html) Open the file, ensure 'X' is ticked for owner, group & everybody, check 'Apply to enclosed', Apply.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had this issue and I found a workaround, which may work for you...

1. Unzip Visual Studio Code in the download folder.
2. Right-click Visual Studio code, in the download folder, and select '*Open*'. If you're prompted by Gatekeeper, open the application.
3. From the '*Code*' menu, select *Preferences* > *User Settings.*
4. Once the settings files open, you can immediately close them both.
5. From the '*Code*' menu, select *Preferences* > *Keyboard Shortcuts*.
6. As with #3, you can immediately close the files.
7. Quit Visual Studio Code
8. Copy the Visual Studio Code application into your *Applications* folder.
9. Open it from *Applications*.

This worked for me - I have no idea why, perhaps a bug to do with accessing the preference file(s)?
Maybe this might work for you?

Comment: FYI: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/92

Answer (score 3):

Moving the `Visual Studio Code.app` into the `~/Applications` folder instead of `/Applications` worked for me.

Comment: The other way around worked for me. All of my other apps were in the `/Applications`. Moving the VS Code app from `~/Applications` to `/Applications` solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just place distribution archive (VSCode-darwin.zip) in `/Aplication` folder and extract it in the same place.
Remove archive after expand.

Answer (score 0):

That's because of the extended attribute `com.apple.quarantine`, you can use `xattr` to remove it from any downloaded app, e.g.:

```
xattr -d -r com.apple.quarantine "/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app"
```

**Note**: use `sudo` to run the above command when necessary.